# What is this method of element instantiation called?

Tags: wpf, object, element, instantiation, creation

Whenever I create a UIElement in code behind, I'd do something like this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "Click Me!";
```

But then I saw this syntax somewhere, and wanted to know what it's called.  I haven't ever seen it used in any of my .NET books:

```
Button button = new Button { Content="Click Me!" };
```

This is obviously nice because it's concise.  So I guess my questions are:

1. what's it called?
2. are there any disadvantages to instantiating a UIElement in this manner?

I've also had trouble figuring out the right way to set properties like CornerRadius and StrokeThickness, and thought the answer to #1 might help me make more intelligent search queries.

Comment: Re: more intelligent search queries...Probably not.  The properties are the same whether you are using direct assignment or object initializers.

Comment: Robert, you're correct, I just tested some searches and it sure didn't help.  And yes, that's what I realized... earlier I was trying to set CornerRadius=3, but didn't realize until I tried setting the CornerRadius property the "normal" way that it should have been CornerRadius=new CornerRadius(3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: An "object initializer"

2: Nope; it is very handy for code samples, in particular ;-p

Things you can't do in an object initializer:

- subscribe events
- combine with collection initializers *on the same collection instance* (an initializer is *either* an object initializer (sets properties) *or* a collection initializer (adds items)

You can get past these limitations by cheating:

```
Button btn;
Form form = new Form { Text = "Hi", Controls = { (btn = new Button()) }};
btn.Click += delegate { ... };
```

Comment: ah! Thanks! And I figured out the last problem, which was that I forgot that thickness is not a double, but a Thickness object.  :)  So everything is great now, thank you.  And if I run into a problem the next time, I'll know to search for "object initializer"!

Comment: thanks for editing and updating your answer, Marc.  I also found the issue with event subscription.  But it is pretty darn nice still.  :)

Answer (score 2):

.Net 3.5 enhancement of Object Initializers, it is just a shorthand mechanism.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is a C# 3.0 thing, not a .NET 3.5 thing - you can use this when targetting .NET 2.0 from a C# 3.0 compiler.

Answer (score 2):

**[Object Initializer](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/09/09/c-3-0-features-object-initializers.aspx)**

It does the same thing under the hood.  Second option uses a single line rather than two, which is nice & concise.  **.NET >= 3.5 only**.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an object initializer and it doesn't have any disadvantages.

Comment: It does have some limitations, though (see my (updated) answer)